# Why does adding a temp variable here make this compiler error go away? The types are the same

Tags: c++

Given the following:

```
#include <string>

class s1
{
    private:
        std::string storage;
    public:
        s1(s1 *newValue) { storage=*newValue; }
        operator std::string () { return storage; }
};

class s2
{
    private:
        std::string storage;
    public:
        s2(s2 *newValue) { std::string temp=*newValue; storage=temp; }
        operator std::string const () { return storage; }
};

class s3
{
    private:
        std::string storage;
    public:
        s3(s3 *newValue) { storage=*newValue; } // Compile Error here.
        operator std::string const () { return storage; }
};
```

The first (s1) and second (s2) examples compile fine; the third one does not... but s2 and s3 should be identical except for passing the value thru the temp variable.

Chasing the error messages into the library code, I *think* that the compiler is trying to bind to a move constructor on std::string in the case of s3.

What I don't understand is why it's doing that; and why I can do what I did with s2, but not s3 --- shouldn't they be the same, semantically?

Any enlightenment anybody can provide would be ***MUCH*** appreciated!

FWIW, the IDE is Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b); and the C++ variant is gnu++17. Also, here's the (slightly redacted) error listing from Xcode:

---

```
In file included from /Users/... big long path here... .cpp:9:
/Users/... big long path here... .hpp:77:31: error: no viable conversion from 's3' to 'std::__1::basic_string<char>'
                        s3(s3 *newValue) { storage=*newValue; }
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Users/... big long path here... .cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/... big long path here... .hpp:45:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:763:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 's3' to 'const std::__1::basic_string<char> &' for 1st argument
    basic_string(const basic_string& __str);
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:768:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 's3' to 'std::__1::basic_string<char> &&' for 1st argument
    basic_string(basic_string&& __str)
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:778:31: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 's3' to 'const value_type *' (aka 'const char *') for 1st argument
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY basic_string(const value_type* __s);
                              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:810:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 's3' to 'initializer_list<value_type>' (aka 'initializer_list<char>') for 1st argument
    basic_string(initializer_list<value_type> __il);
    ^
In file included from /Users/... big long path here... .cpp:9:
/Users/... big long path here... .hpp:78:4: note: candidate function
                        operator std::string const () { return storage; }
                        ^
In file included from /Users/... big long path here... .cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/... big long path here... .hpp:45:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:829:44: note: passing argument to parameter '__str' here
    basic_string& operator=(basic_string&& __str)
                                           ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Compiles for me - perhaps post the calling code?

Comment: I smell compiler bug. GCC compiles all three: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ece01a6e4b336171

Comment: The compilation error is because of [const correctness.](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness).  Naming the input argument the same as the constructor name is ... just ugly.  Don't do it (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution of issue [CWG 1604](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1604) makes it ill-formed to direct-initialize a rvalue reference of class type `T` with an initializer that can be converted to a `const T` rvalue, but an implicit conversion sequence can still be formed because the resolution does not change relevant part about implicit conversion sequence.

As a result, in your example of `s3`, while ranking `string::operator=(const string&)` and `string::operator=(string&&)` during overload resolution, according to [[over.ics.rank]/3.2.3](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.2.3):

> Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence S2 if
>
> - ...
> - S1 and S2 are reference bindings and neither refers to an implicit object parameter of a non-static member function declared without a ref-qualifier, and S1 binds an rvalue reference to an rvalue and S2 binds an lvalue reference
> - ...

the compiler chooses `string::operator=(string&&)` finally, thus causes an error when the initialization of its parameter actually occurs.

In your example of `s2`, the semantic is copy-initializing rather than choosing proper assignment operator, and there is no reference binding. So everything is OK.

Thank T.C. for pointing out that this is already a drafting issue [CWG 2077](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2077) in [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/rz0HWHx4gfU/PJYFaJIhDgAJ).

Answer (score 0):

I would surmise (but it's only going on what your seeing):

**s2(s2 *newValue) { std::string temp=*newValue; storage=temp; }**

Can be completed automatically by the compiler via implicit casting.

Where as:

**s3(s3 *newValue) { storage=*newValue; }**

Cannot.

First place **(*newValue)** in brackets and see if its misinterpreting your intentions in the compiler. Second try performing an explicit cast:

**s3(s3 *newValue) { storage=((std::string)(*newValue)); }**

If neither of those work, I would have to conquer its a compiler issue.

Comment: Parentheses and casts had no effect... it was one of the first things I tried... hence the head scratching. Hmm...